# A non-empty PSR-4 prefix must end with a namespace separator

Tags: composer-php, psr-4

I'm trying to setup PSR-4 with Composer but I'm just getting `A non-empty PSR-4 prefix must end with a namespace separator.`

My `autoload` in my `composer.json` looks like this:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Acme\\models" : "app/models"
    }
},
```

`app/models` is empty.

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 220, accepted):

Someone made a comment but removed it. He mentioned I was missing `\\` at the end of `Acme\\models`. `Acme\\models\\` will get rid of the message and work as it should.

Comment: Yes, `PSR-4` requires the trailing slash. (well double since it needs to be escaped)

Comment: I must say this is not only a stupid requirement, the [spec](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) also makes it extremely clear that this is the case. Hence the reason I show up here for a very basic issue.

Comment: After using this answer, I also found that `composer validate` also gives you a good indication of what's wrong.

Comment: this cause issues when using repository type path, relative, symlinked, as it seems it tries to somehow recreate symlink just after this operation and has obsolete or cached composer.json

Comment: I did this and still got the same error, should I remove the vendor or clear some cache?

Comment: For anyone using **symlinked**, you should delete the symlinked folder before trying again.

Answer (score 12):

As others said `PSR-4 requires the trailing slash`

Though I had to convert `/` to `\\` in Windows (should work fine on Linux):

```json
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

A non-empty PSR-4 prefix must end with a namespace separator.
namespace separator means `\\`

- Method-1

Incorrect ⬇️⬇️⬇️

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Acme\\models" : "app/models"
    }
},
```

Correct ⬇️⬇️⬇️

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Acme\\models" : "app/models/"
    }
},
```

- Method-2: If this doesn't work try deleting vendor + composer.lock and reinstall dependencies
- Method-3: Delete the autoload_psr4.php file in the libraries folder - it probably was created before the update and it had issues before.

[Know more about PSR-4: Autoloader](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/)